# passing Struts 2 property to javascript

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, struts2

I write the following code in simulate.jsp , to receive some String "simulationInfos" from the Server:

```
<s:property id="simulationInfos" value="simulationInfos" /><br/>
```

When simulate.jsp has been returned, I can see, that the String simulationInfos existing.

My Question is: How can I pass simulationsInfos to java script?

I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data=document.getElementById("simulationInfos").value;
console.log("data is: ", data);

And with jQuery:
var data=$("#simulationInfos").val();
</script>
```

and I get the following Error in Firebug: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

How can I pass some struts 2 variable to javascript?

Comment: What does <s:property id="simulationInfos" value="simulationInfos" /> generate as HTML? This is the important part.

Comment: Yes, this property is in the body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should take a look to the HTML code that the JSP is generating. It can explain why you cannot retrieve the value. Then, maybe you will see that you need some extra HTML code. For example:

```
<span id="simulationInfos"><s:property value="simulationInfos" /></span>
```

And in you script:

```
alert("data is: " + simulationInfos.innerHTML);
```

If you take a look to the property tag [doc](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/property.html), you can see that there is not any "id" parameter.

**Edition**: JS correction.

Comment: This works :

var data='<s:property id="simulationInfos" value="simulationInfos" />';
      console.log(data);

Thank you all for participation

Comment: The key is that the property tag was not producing the html you were expecting. Indeed, I bet that no html at all was produced by the property tag so you needed you change your approach ;-)

Comment: I would have just said: var data = "<s:property id="simulationInfos" value="simulationInfos"/>"; If there were quotes in the string there is an attribute of the property tag to encode those too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your id is simulationInfos but you are looking for simulateInfos in your js code. Since your getElementById is not returning anything, there is no value on a (null) return type.

Also, in console.log, use a + to concatenate your strings, not a comma.

Comment: In the firebug console, what do you get when you type document.getElementById("simulationInfos") ?

Comment: I get null for console.log(document.getElementById("simulationInfos") )

Comment: It has nothing to do with console, I tried to split it and I gate the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of null

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to display property values use s:hidden tag like this:

```
<s:hidden id="simulationInfos" value="%{simulationInfos}" name="simulationInfos"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data=$("simulationInfos").value;
console.log("data is: ", data);
</script>
```